# Yii - CGRIDVIEW Additional parameters on pagination

Tags: php, ajax, yii

To make it easy, I have a GridView and I have to pass more parameters to the Ajax Call when I change page. The default parameters are:

- current controller;
- page number;
- ajaxVar (default ajax) with the grid id as default;

I need to pass more parameters because the controller needs more parameters to recreate the correct grid.

On google I have found no answer.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yii is extremly extendable, so you can create a Custom Pagination Widget. Firstly, have a look at this tutorial:

> [How to create a Custom Pagination Widget for Yii Framework](https://sochinda.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/how-to-create-a-custom-pagination-widget-for-yii-framework/)

Here is example from our Project for createPageButton() function in extended Pagination:

```
/**
 * Creates a page button.
 * You may override this method to customize the page buttons.
 *
 * @param string $label the text label for the button
 * @param integer $page the page number
 * @param string $class the CSS class for the page button. This could be 'page', 'first', 'last', 'next' or 'previous'.
 * @param boolean $hidden whether this page button is visible
 * @param boolean $selected whether this page button is selected
 * @return string the generated button
 */
protected function createPageButton($label, $page, $class, $hidden, $selected) {
    if ($hidden || $selected)
        $class .= ' ' . ($hidden ? 'disabled' : 'active');

    return CHtml::tag('li', array(
        'class' => $class
    ), CHtml::link($label, $this->createPageUrl($page).'&pageSize='.$this->pageSize));
}
```

Take a look at following code line:

```
CHtml::link($label, $this->createPageUrl($page).'&pageSize='.$this->pageSize)
```

Url Attribute is `&pageSize=`, and you can extend to any parameters you need with i.e. `. '&myParameter=any_parameter'`

This is definitely the way you can solve your problem and I hope it will help you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.